# Achieving autonomous transaction in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement as below. 
I am using SQL Server 2008. 
1. Table A (Id) 
2. Table B (Id, Attr1, Attr2, Attr3) 
Table A and Table B have same no of rows. Id is primary key in both the tables but there is no referential relationship defined.

I have a trigger on Table A for INSERT. If a record is inserted in Table A, I insert the same ID in Table B and calculate few attributes and populate them in Table B for that ID. I am achieving this using a trigger. 
Now if the transaction fails in Table B, I don't want the transaction in Table A also to be failed. Irrespective of the trigger succeeds or fails in updating Table B, I want the Table A transaction to be success and not to be dependent on Table B transaction. How do I achieve that?

Comment: So, implicit in your question is that you've accepted that there may be times when there are rows in table A but no corresponding rows in table B. Next, we need to determine how *timely* we need to be in rectifying that situation. And that should tell you how often to run e.g. a job or scheduled task that populates table B based on rows in table A with no rows in table B. And take out the (now mostly pointless) trigger.

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying. I got answer from the below thread.
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137305/can-we-commit-the-transaction-when-the-sql-server-trigger-fails

Answer (score 0):

Helpful link [How to create an autonomous transaction in SQL Server 2008](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/08/22/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: Link-only answers tend to be frowned upon here - if the link goes dead, what *useful* information does your answer contain? You don't even tell us the title of the item you're linking to.

Comment: if the official msdn explanation goes dead, this question will be dead as well. if you want an explicit answer, then please wait someone who is not lazy to rewrite same post (from the link)

Comment: Taken from Meta:Linking is not a bad thing as long as you actually provide some context to your answer. If all you are going to do is post a link in your answer, you aren't really answering, you are just providing a detour for the user. At the very least you could explain where the link goes and what it is going to show the user (maybe even quote some of important stuff in the answer so that the OP doesn't have to click the link to possibly answer their question).

Comment: If all you are going to do is post a link in your answer, you aren't really answering, you are just providing a detour for the user